# Prepaid GSM data provider for Connecticut and NYC

Tags: cellphones, new-york-city, data-plans, roaming, connecticut

I'll be traveling to the US (specifically Fairfield, Connecticut) in about 2 weeks. Which provider has the cheapest prepaid data rate? would I be charged roaming if I went to a different city or state? (e.g. New York City). As much as I'd like speed I'd be more concerned about coverage. How soon would they kill the number once I come back to my country? Would I be able to use the same SIM card if I went to Miami in 6 months? If so, being that far from where I bought the SIM, would I then be hit with roaming charges?

Comment: What is NYC? NYC TAM AIR?

Comment: @MarcelC. Common reference to New York City

Comment: @Karlson - GTK & TFTI.

Comment: @Karlson, my friend, that other question does not cover who's the cheapest, nor anyone mentions anything about roaming fees inside the US, maybe no one charges roaming if you go from a city to another inside the US anymore and I was not aware?

Comment: @rantsh If you know the carriers you can find pricing and determine the cheapest.  As far as I know roaming plans you need to specifically look for.  They still exist. :)

Comment: @MarcelC. Ok Ok.

Comment: @karlson: Actually I'm not 100% sure which providers are GSM and which CDMA. I'll Google around, i was just hoping someone knew offhand

Comment: some of your questions might be covered here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/is-it-easy-to-get-prepaid-sims-in-the-us-canada/13698#13698

Comment: @rantsh Sprint, Verizon, Boost = CDMA, AT&T, T-Mobile, SimpleMobile, Virgin Mobile = GSM

Comment: @Karlson Are you sure about Virgin? I thought they were a Sprint VMNO. Aaaaand, I just doublechecked. Virgin is definitely CDMA.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz You're right.  We have friends using a GS3 which I thought was on Virgin but come to think of it they are on SimpleMobile.